# Custom URI kinda flexible file descriptor

Tags: .net, uri

Good afternoon,

I am currently starting to think & prototype about a (.net based) new project which will use MEF extensively and one part will be to plug in new 'storage' types besides a normal file/directory storage (e.g. using scms (clearcase, perforce etc), SAP EDM for long term archiving, OpenText LiveLink etc). Now all of them have the same minimum requirement of R(/W) access, but I need a common format to address all these. I was thinking of using something URI-alike file:// & https:// (livelink uses http(s) for transportation aswell) etc are a common base for all normal ones, but I was wondering whether .Net has functionality to declare new URI types built-in?

What I mean is e.g. that I'd use a similiar format e.g. for clearcase as in 'clearcase:////' or 'sap://identifier' etc etc...

So basically what I am asking and haven't found yet is whether .Net allows me to declare new URI types with its Uri handling classes so I don't have to re-invent the wheel there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Uri` type itself can handle strange URI schemes, like your clearcase:// and sap:// examples above. The `Uri.Scheme` property treats these as plain strings.

There are other answers to 'does .NET support custom URIs?', but those depend on what you want to do with them.